# Change LayoutParams of LinearLayout that is inside of RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I have LinearLayout inside of RelativeLayout. I would like to change height of LinearLayout programmatically. I have tried do this with LinearLayout.LayoutParams but I've got an exception. How to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` as the parent is a RelativeLayout.

The type of the LayoutParams depends on the parent type.